# GtkTreeView - Set user data to a row

Tags: c, gtk, gtktreeview

Is there a way to store user data on a single row in `GtkTreeView`? Like it's usually can be done on any widget with the function `g_object_set_data()`. I tried storing data on `GtkTreeIter` but it produces

> segmentation fault error

The best way to do it I can think of is just to create an additional hidden column. Is it how it should be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a hidden column is how it should be done. (`g_object_set_data()` only works on `GObject`-derived types, and `GtkTreeIter` is not one.)